# CAS with CQL in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, transactions

I'm trying to model some time series data in Cassandra which I had been able to do with the older thrift client but CQL seems to be throwing me off.

I want to add a NEW column to my row IF a specific column value matches.

My table definition is:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable (
   key int,
   base uuid,
   ts int,                   // Timestamp (column name)
   val text,                 // Timestamp value (column value)
   PRIMARY KEY (key, ts)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (ts DESC);
```

What I'm guessing it'd look like is:

```
Row | UUID | TS  | TS | TS
--- | ---- | --- | ---| ---
 1  | id1  |  1  |  2 |  3
--- | ---  | --- | ---| ---
 2  | id2  |  1  |  5 |  6
```

So essentially, I can have a bunch of Timestamps for a given row and a SINGLE UUID for a row. 
The UUID needs to be updated for each new insert of a TS column.

So inserts in a row work just fine:

```
insert into TestTable(key, base, ts, val) values (1, dfb63886-91a4-11e6-ae22-56b6b6499611, 50, 'one')
```

But I'm failing to figure out a way, using CQL, to INSERT a new column in a row using Cassandra transactions (CAS).

This one fails:

```
insert into TestTable(key, base, ts, val) values (1, dfb63886-91a4-11e6-ae22-56b6b6499611, 70, 'four') if base = dfb63886-91a4-11e6-ae22-56b6b6499611;
```

with the error:

```
SyntaxException: <ErrorMessage code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:106 mismatched input 'base' expecting K_NOT (..., 70, 'four') if [base] =...)">
```

And the query:

```
update TestTable set val = 'four', ts=70  where key = 1 if base = dfb63886-91a4-11e6-ae22-56b6b6499611;
```

fails with the error:

```
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="PRIMARY KEY part ts found in SET part"
```

I'm trying to figure out how to model the data properly so that I only have one UUID per row and can have multiple columns without having to explicitly define them during table creation, since it can vary quite a bit.

IIRC, it was easy doing this with the thrift client but using that isn't an option =/

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice tutorial regarding data series [here](https://academy.datastax.com/resources/getting-started-time-series-data-modeling)

In a nutshell, your composite key will be your unique identifier (like the UUID that you were proposing) and a timestamp, so you will be able to add as many events/values associated to a UUID

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TestTable (
   base uuid,
   ts timestamp,             // Timestamp (column name)
   value text,                 // Timestamp value (column value)
   PRIMARY KEY (base, ts)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (ts DESC);
```

Adding values will have the same UUID with different times:

```
INSERT INTO TestTable (base, ts, value) 
    VALUES (467286c5-7d13-40c2-92d0-73434ee8970c, dateof(now()), 'abc');

INSERT INTO TestTable (base, ts, value) 
    VALUES (467286c5-7d13-40c2-92d0-73434ee8970c, dateof(now()), 'def');

cqlsh:test> SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE base = 467286c5-7d13-40c2-92d0-73434ee8970c;

 base                                 | ts                              | value
--------------------------------------+---------------------------------+-------
 467286c5-7d13-40c2-92d0-73434ee8970c | 2016-10-14 04:13:42.779000+0000 |   def
 467286c5-7d13-40c2-92d0-73434ee8970c | 2016-10-14 04:12:50.551000+0000 |   abc

(2 rows)
```

Updating can be done in any of the columns, *except the ones used as keys*, the errors displayed in the update statement was caused by the "IF" statement and because it was tried to update `ts` which is part of the composite key.

```
INSERT INTO TestTable (base, ts, value)
       VALUES (ffb0bb8e-3d67-4203-8c53-046a21992e52, dateof(now()), 'bananas');

SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE base = ffb0bb8e-3d67-4203-8c53-046a21992e52 AND ts < dateof(now());

 base                                 | ts                              | value
--------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------
 ffb0bb8e-3d67-4203-8c53-046a21992e52 | 2016-10-14 04:17:26.421000+0000 | apples

(1 rows)

UPDATE TestTable SET value = 'apples' WHERE base = ffb0bb8e-3d67-4203-8c53-046a21992e52;

SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE base = ffb0bb8e-3d67-4203-8c53-046a21992e52 AND ts < dateof(now());

 base                                 | ts                              | value
--------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------
 ffb0bb8e-3d67-4203-8c53-046a21992e52 | 2016-10-14 04:17:26.421000+0000 | bananas

(1 rows)
```

Comment: so there is no way in CQL to add arbitrary columns and use CAS?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to add dynamic columns to a row, the explanation is [here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/does-cql-support-dynamic-columns-wide-rows)

Comment: The way the table is currently setup, it does add dynamic columns.

Comment: What I'm looking for is a way to add dynamic columns WITH CAS (transactions)